# Appendix in APA paper: Can a document in an appendix span multiple pages?

Tags: publications, formatting

I need to put a multiple-page document in an appendix of my APA paper.

1. Is it ok to have an appendix span multiple pages?
2. If so, after the first Appendix A page, do I title subsequent pages as "Appendix A cont."?

Thank you for any help!